# How to set up envoirment variables for a perl script in crontab properly? Script is executing with workarounds

Tags: linux, perl, cron, environment-variables

Sorry for the long question but I'm bit lost please help me out. I've got the following problem:

OS: `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)`

Perl: `This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi`

Module in question: `DBD::Oracle`

Quick description:

I have an perl script that runs just fine from the command line. When setting it up in crontab like this:

`* * * * * \path\to\script.pl`

the following error is generated :

```
Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 190.
```

So far this is what i have tried :

Setting up this block in the begging of the script - same error for crontab execution.

```
BEGIN {
    $ENV{'ORACLE_HOME'}='/opt/oracli/app/oracli/product/12.2.0/client_1';
    $ENV{'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'}='/opt/oracli/app/oracli/product/12.2.0/client_1/lib:/lib:/usr/lib';
}
```

Adding the following lines to /home/user/.bash_profile (same crontab user)

```
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracli/app/oracli/product/12.2.0/client_1; export ORACLE_HOME
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Correcting does lines in /home/user/.bashrc (because they were messed up there)

Re-loading both .bash_profile & .bashrc

Adding this in the begging of my crontab:

```
BASH_ENV=/home/user/.bash_profile
```

All of the above didn't help me. My source was google and working under the assumption that I'm not providing the ORACLE_HOME & LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

When i run a simple shell script that contains :

```
#!/bin/sh

ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracli/app/oracli/product/12.2.0/client_1
export ORACLE_HOME
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracli/app/oracli/product/12.2.0/client_1/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/path/to/script.pl
```

Everythign is working just fine so...

Please point me in what am I missing. Is there a different config file in linux for the crontab envoirment.

Sorry for the long post I'm not just that into the OS.

Edit : Sorry i missed this - i want to bypass if possible shell exporting the variables needed invoking the perl :

```
* * * * * \path\to\shell_with_variables.sh
```

But to find where I can add the variables globaly so they are visible from crontab executions

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shell spawend by cron has very minimal set of environment variables. I see that you've partially solved your problem. You need to set the variables you have created in the example shell script in the crontab file itself - either by prepending the variable declarations or by setting them up somewhere in the file.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed this in the post. When running the example shell scripts in crontab everything works just fine. But I want if possible to bypass the creation of shell script that is invoking the perl script (due to large amount of scripts planned) I want if possible to add the envoirment variables in config file that will provide (make the ENV variables visible) for the crontab for this user. I will edit the original post. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: That's quite an old version of Perl. About (30-10)/2+1 = 11 years old?

Answer (score 4):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` needs to be set before the program (`perl`) starts.

---

You can use

```
ORACLE_HOME=...
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...

* * * * * /path/to/script.pl
```

or

```
* * * * * ORACLE_HOME=... LD_LIBRARY_PATH=... /path/to/script.pl
```

The first sets it for all cron jobs. The latter for just that one program.

---

A third option is to fix the environment and relaunch `perl`.

```
BEGIN {
   if (@ARGV && $ARGV[0] eq '!fixed!') {
      shift(@ARGV);
   } else {
      $ENV{ ORACLE_HOME     } = "...";
      $ENV{ LD_LIBRARY_PATH } = "...";
      exec($^X, "--", $0, '!fixed!', @ARGV)
         or die("exec: $!\n");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add the environment variables at the top of the crontab file itself.

```
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracli/app/oracli/product/12.2.0/client_1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracli/app/oracli/product/12.2.0/client_1/lib
* * * * * /path/to/script.pl
```

Alternatively...

As some of the other comments have suggested, if you add environment variables in `~/.bashrc`, cron will not pick them up. You can, however, use a bash wrapper to call your Perl.

```sh
#!/bin/bash -l
exec /path/to/script.pl
```

Your crontab file should then call the wrapper instead of your Perl program.

See also [crontab(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab).