# how to make cpan modules available in cron

Tags: perl, cron

My perl script, jaw20230325printcalendartodisk.pl,
depends on `File::Rsync`.
I had to do `cpan File::Rsync` to get this module on my computer,
which is macbook pro, macos Ventura 13.4.

The script
jaw20230325printcalendartodisk.pl
does not directly use `File::Rsync` but
rather uses a perl module I wrote,
QuemQuaeritis.pm,
which uses `File::Rsync`.

jaw20230325printcalendartodisk.pl
runs fine on the command line.
But I want to run it under cron:

```
> crontab -l
00 16  *  *  *  $HOME/u/kh/pm/jaw20230325printcalendartodisk.pl
```

and this leads to the following error:

```
Can't locate File/Rsync.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::Rsync module) (@INC contains: /Users/kpr/u/kh/pm
/usr/local/opt/perl/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/opt/perl/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36
/usr/local/opt/perl/lib/perl5/5.36/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/opt/perl/lib/perl5/5.36 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36) at
/Users/kpr/u/kh/pm/QuemQuaeritis.pm line 2061.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Users/kpr/u/kh/pm/QuemQuaeritis.pm line 2061.
Compilation failed in require at /Users/kpr/u/kh/pm/jaw20230325printcalendartodisk.pl line 39.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Users/kpr/u/kh/pm/jaw20230325printcalendartodisk.pl line 39.
```

So it appears that cpan made `File::Rsync` available in my shell, but not under cron.

jaw20230325printcalendartodisk.pl  **used to run fine under cron**, but
this week
I  did `brew install python`  on this machine.
It then installed something called python3.
Only
after that installation did my code stop running under cron.

Based on warnings that were printed when I ran cpan,
the following has been the final line in my .bash_profile for four months:

```
eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/perl5)"
```

This is supposed to mean that I do not have to reinstall modules each time the macos is upgraded.

Thus, how do I make my cpan modules available under cron, i.e., when I am not running in the shell?

Or alternatively, how can I prevent an installation of
python3 from interfering with the accessibility of my
cpan-installed perl modules?

Additional information:

```
> perldoc -l File::Rsync
/Users/kpr/perl5/lib/perl5/File/Rsync.pm
```

I believe this is consistent with the final line of .bash_profile above.
I think that line means that when I install a module under cpan,
it is put under my HOME directory, not where the rest of perl is installed.

Comment: Can you try determine the location of the file `Rsync.pm` corresponding to the module `File::Rsync` ? Try run the following command from command line: `perl -MFile::Rsync -E 'say $INC{"File/Rsync.pm"}'`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/59683121/2173773

Comment: How do you load `File::Rsync` -- is it simply `use File::Rsync;` or do you first need `use lib "path/to/prog";`?  (What should be a fix for the cron-ed run, to add `use lib "/full/path/to/prog";` before `use File::Rsync;`, so that perl interpreter surely looks where that is installed.)  And, do tell where that module is installed (`perldoc -l File::Rsync` should work as well)

Comment: @zdim do you mean literally "/full/path/to/prog", or does that stand for ````> which perl
/usr/local/bin/perl````? But the cpan library is under HOME.

Comment: @zdim and https://perldoc.perl.org/lib, I have added to the start of my QuemQuaeritis.pm module the following: `use lib /Users/kpr/perl5; `

Comment: @JacobWegelin "_I have added ... `use lib /Users/kpr/perl5`_" -- OK, now what is the full path to `File::Rsync` (so to `File/Rsync.pm`)?  The path in `use lib ...` should lead to a directory that contains the directory `File` in which `Rsync.pm` file is

Comment: @zdim the full path is `/Users/kpr/perl5/lib/perl5/File/Rsync.pm`. I added information to my original post, invoking `perldoc -l File::Rsync`. I did not know if it is better to give `/Users/kpr/perl5/lib/perl5/File` or just `/Users/kpr/perl5`.

Comment: @JacobWegelin "_...do you mean literally..._"  Let's say I install a module `Mod::Name` as a user.  Then I find where it went: `perldoc -l Mod::Name` (on the command line), and this gives me `/home/username/perl5/lib/perl5/Mod/Name.pm`.  (If `perldoc` doesn't give use Hakon's program above.)  So you say `use lib "/home/.../perl5/lib/perl5";`.  Then  you have `use Mod::Name;` and the interpreter (perl) will look through `@INC` for `Name.pm` in a directory `Mod/`, while the `use lib ...` statement added the path `/nfs/...perl5` to `@INC`. So `perl` finds the module there and loads it

Comment: @JacobWegelin "_the full path is..._" -- OK, so you need `use lib '/Users/kpr/perl5/lib/perl5/';` and then later `use File::Rsync;` should work

Comment: @JacobWegelin "_...if it is better to give..._"  -- When `use File::Rsync;` is executed the interpreter looks in each entry in `@INC` (which are directories) for a directory `File/` (and when it finds it looks in it for the file `Rsync.pm`).  So the entry (in `@INC`) that is `/Users/kpr/perl5/lib/perl5/File` does not have a directory `File/` in it!  Whle `/Users/kpr/perl5/lib/perl5` does, so that's what you want.  The directory that has `File/Rsync.pm`.

Comment: Btw, when programs run out of crontab they are in a restricted environment; they should not rely on user's shell configuration.  The program that is to run should better set up everything.

Comment: One can set up some environment variables in `crontab(5)`, and `MAILTO=user@email.host` is pretty much compulsory, so that _you_ get email when something's wrong -- without that `cron(8)` sends emails to ... the root!  Clearly, the root likely ignores them (otherwise sysadmins on larger systems would never sleep...).  Also see `crontab(1)`.

Comment: (The numbers in parens are man page sections, like `man 5 crontab`.  The `man 8 cron` and `man 1 crontab` in this case are defaults so numbers aren't needed)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your crontab:

```bash
PERL5LIB=/Users/kpr/perl5/lib/perl5
```

Or possibly

```bash
PERL5LIB=$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5
```

This will have the same effect local::lib. (Well, the relevant part of it. You can run `perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/perl5` to see all the vars it sets.)

Answer (score 1):

Jobs run out of `crontab(5)` are in a restricted environment and a program cannot simply rely on the user's shell environment and configuration.  One way out of that is to set up everything in the program.

When the interpreter needs to load a module it searches paths given in the global [@INC](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#@INC) array for it.  In this case it'll look for a directory `File` and then for a file `Rsync.pm` in it.  Also see [require](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require), and [perlmod](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod).

So if this module is installed in a location which isn't already in `@INC` then one needs to add to `@INC` that path, in which `File/Rsync.pm` is.  The best way to do that is via the [lib](https://perldoc.perl.org/lib) pragma.

The question gives the module's location as `/Users/kpr/perl5/lib/perl5/File/Rsync.pm` so

```
use lib '/Users/kpr/perl5/lib/perl5';

use File::Rsync;
```

Now this should be able to run via cron.

---

A comment clarifies that `/Users/kpr` is the home directory, as it may seem. Then it is indeed better to use [$ENV{HOME}](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#%25ENV) instead,

```
use lib "$ENV{HOME}/perl5/lib/perl5";
```

More specifically, the comment states that this is different on other machines (so on those machines the module is installed in different directories), and then this also makes it a good example of portability issues.

Comment: If you run the same perl code on different machines, this won't work.
On one machine of mine, `$HOME` is /Users/kpr; on another, /Users/vxv.
This is why I use `use lib $ENV{HOME} . '/perl5/lib/perl5/';`.

Comment: @JacobWegelin OK, that's a good point. The question gave a specific path, without saying that it was the home (nor did it give the path as a home directory), so I could've not divined that it was home.  Also, there was no talk of portability, just a particular path given.  But if it is home you are absolutely right, better write it as such.

Comment: @JacobWegelin (I see now that your edit mentions this explicitly)

Comment: cheers if that's someone's reason for a -1...

Comment: @JacobWegelin Added this to the answer, thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

[@ikegami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76486388/1990570) will almost certainly work for you, but another (more general)  solution is to get cron to run a command via your shell. This ensures that all the usual environment your shell provides for you will be available.

Something like this in crontab:

```
00 16 *  *  *  /usr/bin/bash -c "$HOME/u/kh/pm/jaw20230325printcalendartodisk.pl"
```

This is slightly less efficient, but for a script run once per day, a few extra microseconds of runtime is likely not a concern.

Answer (score -1):

Recall that
QuemQuaeritis.pm holds the subs for my module,
including the sub that was trying to run when I got the error.

The script that ran under my shell but **not** in crontab invoked a sub that contained
`use File::Rsync;`.
It was at that line that the error was thrown under cron/crontab.

Thanks to comments,   I put the following into the early lines of QuemQuaeritis.pm :

`use lib $ENV{HOME} . '/perl5/lib/perl5/';`

and then my script ran fine under cron.